# Nginx - PHP file is downloaded instead of 404 error (Piwigo Docker)

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I will preface this by saying that I almost always use Apache, but am trying Nginx while moving some stuff to a docker container. I am using the Piwigo Docker image from LinuxServer.io located [here](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-piwigo), and there is an open issue for this pro, but it has yet to be resolved. So, I am hoping that someone here could possibly point me in the right direction. For testing, if anyone is interested, the issue can be seen on a completely clean pull after setup.

**Issue**: Accessing any page or folder that doesn't exist gives one of two outcomes.
Outcome 1: attempt to access /fakepage.html or /fakepage = PHP file is downloaded instead of served.
Outcome 2: attempt to access /fakepage.php = empty page with "File not found" in the top left.

All configs are shown in the Github link above, but shown here for context.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

server_name _;

set $root /app/www/public;
if (!-d /app/www/public) {
    set $root /config/www;
}
root $root;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location / {
    # enable for basic auth
    #auth_basic "Restricted";
    #auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php$is_args$args =404;
}

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess/.htpasswd files
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
   }
}
```

When 404 pages should be shown/logged, instead everything is logged as a 200 regardless of file downloaded or "file not found" error shown.

This issue exists on HTTP or HTTPS attempts.

I have tried this in the following Docker Hosts; Rocky 8, Rocky 9, Windows 10, and Ubuntu 22.04

I have changed themes in Piwigo and checked permissions and paths as suggested in other posts.

Here is a sample of what the downloaded php file looks like.

```
<?php
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
// | This file is part of Piwigo.                                          |
// |                                                                       |
// | For copyright and license information, please view the COPYING.txt    |
// | file that was distributed with this source code.                      |
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

//--------------------------------------------------------------------- include
define('PHPWG_ROOT_PATH','./');
include_once( PHPWG_ROOT_PATH.'include/common.inc.php' );
include(PHPWG_ROOT_PATH.'include/section_init.inc.php');

// Check Access and exit when user status is not ok
check_status(ACCESS_GUEST);


// access authorization check
if (isset($page['category']))
{
  check_restrictions($page['category']['id']);
}
if ($page['start']>0 && $page['start']>=count($page['items']))
```

Comment: If a file is not found, `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php$is_args$args =404;` will try to return `index.html` if it exists or otherwise **download** `index.php`. If you want to use 404 when a file is not found, use: `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` - see [the `try_files` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: Oh man, you saved me! Thank you so much. With your info, I was able to fix it as well as dug a little deeper and created a custom 404 error page. Now everything is working as expected including proper 404 logging.